# Role base login claim in .NET 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, cookies

I want to make 2 separate logins for admin and user.

I wrote 2 different controllers, one for admin which created at in area/admin, the other is for users which created at in controller.

Admin controller code:

```
public IActionResult PostLogin(LoginModel model)
{
    UserLoginData user = _accountRepository.GetUserLoginData(model.UserName, model.Password);

    if (user != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", user.UserName);
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("UserId", user.UserId);

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName.ToString()));
        string[] roles = user.Role.RoleName.Split(",");

        foreach (string role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Admin", "Admin");
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties();
        props.IsPersistent = false;
        props.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2);
        HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, props).Wait();
       return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home", new { area = "Admin" });
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["NotValid"] = "Invalid username or password. Please try again.";
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid username or password. Please try again.");
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```

User controller:

```
public IActionResult PostLogin(UserLoginData model)
{
    UserLoginData user = _accountRepository.GetUserLoginData(model.EmailId, model.Password);

    if (user != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Email", user.EmailId);
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("usrid", user.UserId);

        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.EmailId.ToString()));
        string[] roles = { "Customer" };

        foreach (string role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }

        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("Customer", "1");

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        
        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
        var props = new AuthenticationProperties();
        props.IsPersistent = false;
        props.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2);
        HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, props).Wait();

        return RedirectToAction("products", "home");
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["NotValid"] = "Invalid username or password. Please try again.";
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid username or password. Please try again.");
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
}
```

`Program.cs` code:

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/admin/account/login");
        options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    })
    .AddCookie("Customer", options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/account/login");
        options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "areas",
      pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Dashboard}/{id?}"
    );
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

Now I have provide my admin controller and user controller code basically both are same name `AccountController` but both are in different place one is on Area/Admin and one is on controller (noraml path).

Now what happening with above code is like if I make authorization on any user page then if I haven't login then it's redirecting on `/account/login` it's fine but now if i am accessing admin page without login then it's also redirecting me on `/account/login` instead of `/admin/account/login` I have tried many things which I got still not get any proper way or solution.

I would like to you guys please check the above things and help me out to solve this problem. And thanks in advance for whoever can give their time to solve this problem and help me learn something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your example, It's better to have a single login endpoint. In your implementation you have to decide user is an admin or not based on URL. I think that a decision should be made after you retrieve the data at this line,

```
UserLoginData user = _accountRepository.GetUserLoginData(model.EmailId, model.Password);
```

You should use roles to decide user is an admin or not.

To fix your specific problem your cookie setup should updated like this,

```
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    // Common settings for user authentication
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/account/accessdenied");
})
.AddCookie("AdminAuthScheme", options =>
{
    // Settings specific for admin authentication
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/admin/account/login");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/admin/account/accessdenied");
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
        {
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/admin") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 401)
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect("/admin/account/login");
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
})
```

Your admin controllers authorized like this

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AdminAuthScheme")]
public class YourAdminController : Controller
{
    // Your admin actions
}
```

Comment: Hlo @Akalanka Dissanayake thank you for your great help. the above code changes working now I know how to make multiple logins with different paths. thank you for giving your time to solve this problem.